# .NET unable to get past "Bad Authentication data" Twitter API 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, twitter, oauth

Attempting to utilize the Twitter 1.1 API for a simple read/search tweets application. For the life of me I can't authenticate against the API. I created a Twitter application via `apps.twitter.com`, read through the documentation and thought I'll test this from within the Postman REST Client. Punched in all my tokens into the `OAuth 1.0` tab and got the dreaded `{"message": "Bad Authentication data","code":215}`

Double checked everything and still the same error. Read some more documentation and saw that "Application-only authentication" needs to go through OAuth 2.0. Tried that out still the same `Bad Authentication` message.

Since I will be doing this in `.NET` I figured why not try out a sample application. Followed the steps [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net) to construct an OAuth request. Result - another 401 response.

Looked through the suggested libraries on twitter's website for `.NET` and found `Tweetinvi`. Their documentation was simple enough. Running a simple snippet of the library:

```
var credentials = TwitterCredentials.CreateCredentials("Access_Token", "Access_Token_Secret", "Consumer_Key", "Consumer_Secret");
TwitterCredentials.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials(credentials, () =>
{
    Tweet.PublishTweet("myTweet");
});
```

was fruitless as well. At this point i've all, but given up. Something as trivial as calling an API has left me speechless.

The documentation is vast and robust, but it has proven difficult to understand. Is there something possibly that I need to do with my actual twitter account rather than the twitter application?

If it helps solve my problem, my application is set for `Read Only` permissions.

Comment: Did you try the code exactly as you post in the question?

Comment: @faby Yes, aside from the fact that I replaced `Access_Token_Secret` etc. with the actual key values.

Comment: But if your application is set for read only you can't pubblish tweet (need write permissions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you are trying to publish a tweet with this code:

```
var credentials = TwitterCredentials.CreateCredentials("Access_Token", "Access_Token_Secret", "Consumer_Key", "Consumer_Secret");
TwitterCredentials.ExecuteOperationWithCredentials(credentials, () =>
{
    Tweet.PublishTweet("myTweet");
});
```

But at the same time you are saying that your app is set for Read Only permissions. Publish a tweet needs other permissions.

Comment: Wow. I've been up all night trying to figure that out. Would you happen to know why I wouldn't be able to read the API via a GET method in Postman Client - `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2`